# What is an efficient database management system for rarely changing data?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, immutability, database

I am looking for an efficient relational database management system that is optimized for rarely changing data (rarely enough that even having to recreate the entire database on every change would be acceptable). For example, I do *not* need transactions, user accounts, triggers, or any other fancy features; but I *do* need foreign keys, joins, and the ability to store large amounts of data (although not quite "Big Data").

The only two DBMS's I am familiar with are MySQL and SQLite:

- MySQL seems like way too much overhead.
- SQLite seems like it won't scale too well for larger amounts of data.

Comment: I don't think any entire RDBMS are specialized for read-only.  Probably more important to ask how to design a schema and indices optimized for read-only.

Comment: I'm not sure where the question is .. simple *don't* use the features that aren't needed and *do* create the properly normalized/indexed schema that is (and there is *no way* this can be answered within the given context) .. then trust the query planner and caching. Of course, *maybe an SQL/relational database isn't appropriate* at all ..

Comment: Consider [myisampack](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/myisampack.html).

Comment: Basically anything with a query cache, ie: mysql.

Comment: @user2246674 I'm ok with that as long as the features I don't use don't create much overhead.

Comment: @Matt Why would not used features "create [relevant] overhead"? This question seems like a non-issue (e.g. the actual problem is not well-defined nor is any issue tested) as it is written. Also the "overheads" imagined are not strictly warranted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of at least two features that you can take advantage of, given that you require few or no updates.

**Somewhat De-normalized**

De-normalizing data can be problematic for changing databases, as it forces you to make multiple updates for all the redundancies.  Since that is not a concern in this case, you're free to de-normalize some tables in order to facilitate queries.  That is, more of the data you need can be in a fewer tables -- hence fewer joins, faster queries.

For example, a fully normalized database may have a "users" table and a "locations" table, where "users" contains a "location_id" foreign key.  You might decide to de-normalize, and remove the "locations" table, moving all its columns into the "users" table.  That way, any query against users + locations will not need to perform the join.

**Highly Indexed**

Catalog the queries you expect, and design indices (and/or indexed views) to ensure fast lookup in all cases.  Normally you are limited in this, because more indices mean slower inserts -- but freed of that, you can index to your heart's content.  Of course, indices take up disk space, so you still need to consider that, but for mid-sized databases, space is normally less problematic than speed.

---

In terms of RDBMS, I don't think it matters that much (at least from the standpoint of optimizing for read-only databases -- of course there are other important factors like licensing costs).  Any of the traditional relational databases -- MySQL, SQL Server -- will force you into horizontal partitioning, should you ever need to expand beyond one server.

The big-data solutions (Hadoop, MongoDB) may be worth considering, as they may facilitate multi-server scaling.  That's what they're designed for, and some of their drawbacks (esp. lack of ability to join) will be mitigated for your case.

Comment: "*Somewhat* De-normalized". Too much de-normalization can actually be detrimental - even without requiring "extra joins". I always start with "full" normalization; but like with the index suggestion, this question is far too vague/incomplete to provide more than vague "suggestions". Once a database is selected, then it comes down to tuning it against the expected usage.

Comment: @Matt yes, I realize that -- I still thought it was worth mentioning for completeness' sake.  So you're sure you'll be safely confined to one server?  There would be some benefit to those, even if you end up spanning only two servers.